# Keychain value removed after adding com.apple.security.application-groups

Tags: ios, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

After adding the necessary entitlements for enabling App Groups, my user credentials got wiped (they were stored in the keychain). The query I am using to save the password is:

```
NSData *valueData = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: service,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: key,
                        (__bridge id)kSecValueData: valueData,
                        };
```

And then fetching it:

```
NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                        (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: service,
                        (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
                        (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue};
```

The only key that my entitlements have is:

```
com.apple.security.application-groups
```

Which is an array with my bundle identifier inside. Am I missing something in the entitlements file?

Comment: They were in all probability not "wiped" just that now you are accessing the keychain differently with the new entitlement.

Comment: Is there a possibility of accessing them with the new entitlement?

Comment: I suspect that would be a security violation since the keychain values were created to be used only by the single app and now multiple apps could access the values. You might do better asking this on the Apple Developer Forum where there are Apple staff who many times respond to questions.

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve this?